# Is there a console interface for the Client Monitor on OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal, automation

I'm writing a bash-script at work for controlling our Mac-computers (OS X Mountain Lion) remotely. Since we use FileWave in our Company we just have to remove an Application and restart the computer. Then it will be installed from the FileWave server. Another way to do it is to uninstall and run the Client Monitor under Programs and press "Verify". Is there any way to make this "Verify"-request via the terminal?

Comment: What is Client Monitor? Also What Application needs to be removed - this sounds like a much bigger issue.

Comment: Client Monitor is a application that checks the computers software and compares it with FileWave. The files thats missing gets sent out to the machine again. I can't find any information about Client Monitor itselfs, but I guess it's the Client part of FileWave. The Program removed is not really an issue, we use it to remove for example Firefox, wich works fine. Just "rm -rf" on the .app-directory of the application then a reboot and the program will be installed again. But if you use the Client Monitor you don't need the reboot.

Comment: A program/environment should have quite a bit of documentation and I suggest looking there. If it does not have the docs I would not trust it considering what we know part of it does, ie installing apps

Comment: Thank you for your last commend Mark. Anyhow. The Client Monitor runs against the FileWave-service fwcld.

Comment: Found the solution. Restart the FW-service on the Mac. "sudo systemstarter stop fwcld".

Comment: I've reopened this, it's not at all too localized and in fact - asks a good question with two answers. 1) Is there a command line equivalent (in this case - yes). 2) Can UI controls be scripted (yes) and what tools are needed (TBD).

Comment: We love jeopardy questions where you can come in and answer your own question. Would you mind answering this with the fwcld command? It will help many others that use this software to know you found a solution.